# Jboss Wildfly 8.1 session timeout on login page

Tags: authentication, jboss, session-timeout, j-security-check

I have an application running on JBoss 8.1 with JAAS form based login (j_security_check) and everything works fine.

My problem is:
1) the user logs out and is redirected on the login page
2) here a session timeout occurs (the user doesn't know this)
3) the user returns and logs in correctly
=> BAM: he is redirected with j_security_check (the URI ends with j_security_check), but the page is empty.

My guess is: JBoss doesn't know anymore the previously requested page, because the session timeout occurs and this information is lost. So JBoss doesn't know where to send the now logged in user and the page stays empty.

I found some posts but no real answer/solution for this problem. 
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you find any solution? I have same problem!